# show the JW player

Tags: php, ajax, jwplayer

I have page that has a text input and a button
the user must fill a URL which is  referring to a playable media file(mp4) in the text field and click the button

when the button is clicked the a script is running and ajax is passing the url value to PHP file which do some verifications and send the response back

if every thing is ok it should replace the DIV tag with JW player  and the user can play the media

I test the whole process by replacing the DIV tag with a plain text or image and it worked smoothly

and when I tried to replace it with the jw player component it is not showing any thing

I tested the jw by inserting it directly in the HTML code and it worked smoothly

### here is the full index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ajax4/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="RXVe0CXFsIS8pAar5ezgSLJqb9jfx7rDOBxkVw==";</script>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--

    function get_XmlHttp() {
      var xmlHttp = null;

      if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {       // for Forefox, IE7+, Opera, Safari, ...
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else if(window.ActiveXObject) {   // for Internet Explorer 5 or 6
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      return xmlHttp;
    }

    // sends data to a php file, via POST, and displays the received answer
    function ajaxrequest(php_file, tagID) {
      var request =  get_XmlHttp();     // call the function for the XMLHttpRequest instance

      // create pairs index=value with data that must be sent to server
      var hiturl = document.getElementById('hit').value;
      var  the_data = 'hiturl='+hiturl;

      request.open("POST", php_file, true);         // set the request

      // adds  a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
      request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      request.send(the_data);       // calls the send() method with datas as parameter

      // Check request status
      // If the response is received completely, will be transferred to the HTML tag with tagID
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          document.getElementById(tagID).innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
      }
    }
    --></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="test_form.php" method="post" name="form1" onsubmit="ajaxrequest('hitphp.php', 'myDiv'); return false;">
    <label for="name" id="name_label">hit URL: </label>  
    <input type="text" name="hit" id="hit" size="100"  /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Enter hit UrL" />

    </form>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

## and the hitphp.php file

```
    <?php
    // if data are received via POST
    if (isset($_POST['hiturl'])) {
      // get data into variables, deleting the html tags
      $hiturl = strip_tags($_POST['hiturl']);

      // if the form fields are completed
      if (true) {
        if (true) {


    echo'<div id="myElement">nnnnn.....</div><script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("myElement").setup({

    type:"mp4", 
    bufferlength: "60",
    file: "mediaurl",


});


</script>';



}else{
echo 'sorry not a valid url';
}
      }
      else {
        echo 'Fill in all form fields';
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are trying to run this?

Comment: actually I am testing it locally using WAMP

Comment: Oh, hmmm...can you put something up if possible?

Comment: currently I cant ... but if there is any further information that can help I am ready to supply them

Comment: Can you email a link to us that we can then test / debug locally? http://www.longtailvideo.com/contact-us

Comment: full code added  hope that will help ... note that I omitted the verification conditions in the php code for private reasons

Comment: Yes, that code looks OK. I really need to be able to see something to debug it properly though.